# AngularJS location.hash animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs I'm using **$location.hash('id_bottom');** to scroll down to the bottom of the page. Its very quick and jumpy. Is there a way using angularjs to nicely scroll down i.e. slower? (animation?).

If so could someone show my how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where using jQuery is OK. If you are using jQuery, check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) and [this plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.gr/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). You can even wrap the call into an Angular service, so you could use something like:

```
app.controller("...", function($scope, scrollTo) {
    ...
    scrollTo("id_bottom");
    ...
});
```